# Boto3 upload_file uploads partial wav files

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

We're seeing a intermittent issue where .wav files are being partially uploaded to an S3 bucket.

E.g. if a file example.wav of size 3mb we sometimes see 1mb in the S3 bucket.

When we listen to the file, its clear that it has only partially uploaded the file.

Other times this works without issue and regardless of file size (large or small)

Boto3 version: 1.9.22
Python version: 3.5.2

Comment: You've ruled out any chance of error in the upload client?

Comment: @jarmod As best we can, but i'm curious as to how you would rule out chance of error?

Comment: Amazon S3 claims to never add partial objects. If you receive a success response, then Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket. Which boto3 API function are you using? Is the problem easily reproducible? Some ideas ... Can you run it on a different network (maybe guest wifi or other) to remove any potential proxy issues? Run boto3 with full debug. Enable CloudTrail S3 logging to see if it provides insight. Maybe even proxy (mitmproxy?) the entire file upload so that you can intercept the traffic and ensure that all expected bytes were sent and expected response was received.

Comment: @jarmod upload_file is the function being used https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file 
Its being run all within AWS so no issues with proxies etc...